# How to hide the Accordion widget detail?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I'm having trouble with the Expand/Not Expand. I've followed instruction from the Vendor rating template but still no luck..

What I've done :

1. Creating an paper accordion widget (not cards) named *AccordionServeur* with this script in the `onDataLoad` event :

```
var rows = widget.children._values;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      if (rows[i].name.indexOf('AccordionServeurDetail') === -1) {
        rows[i].styles = ['collapsed'];
      }
    }
```

2. Add some TextBox inside the AccordionServeurRow to edit the value (i.e. with datalink)
3. Create the client script with this code:

```
function expandAccordionRow(accordionRow) {
  var rows = accordionRow.parent.children._values;
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (rows[i].name.indexOf('AccordionServeurDetail') > -1) {
      rows[i].styles = [];
    } else {
      rows[i].styles = ['collapsed'];
    }
  }
  accordionRow.styles = [];
}
```

```
function collapseAccordionRow(accordionRow) {
  var rows = accordionRow.parent.children._values;
  var i = 0;
  accordionRow.styles = ['collapsed'];
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (rows[i].name.indexOf('AccordionServeurDetail') > -1) {
      rows[i].styles = ['hidden'];
    }
  }
}
```

```
function toggleAccordionRow(accordionRow) {
  if (accordionRow.styles.length === 0) {
     collapseAccordionRow(accordionRow);
  } else {
        expandAccordionRow(accordionRow);
  }
}
```

4. On the AccordionServeurRow, in the `onAttach` event, I run this script:

```
widget.styles = ['collapsed'];
widget.getElement().removeAttribute('aria-expanded');
```

5. On the AccordionServeurRow, in the `onClick` event, I run this script:

```
toggleAccordionRow(widget);
```

6. On the AccordionServeurDetail, in the `dataLoad` event, I run this script:

```
widget.styles=['hidden'];
```

But it still expands the detail when I open the page where the widget is.
Plus the detail stays expanded event if I click on the AccordionRow.
Did I miss something in the script or is it because of parameters in the widget ?

EDIT : 
I've found the solution. You have to create style "collapsed" and to call them in the script above :

```
.app-AccordionRow.collapsed {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.app-AccordionDetail.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Are you not using the prebuilt Accordion widget? That widget will automatically handle the expand/collapse for you, although it is built more so to handle datasource items. So if you are referring to more of a custom application, than the prebuilt Accordion might not work for you.

Comment: Hi Markus, I'm using the prebuilt Accordion. But I just want to have the same behaviour as the Accordion widget in the companies page from the Vendor ratings template ( link to the template : https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/vendor-ratings) . They manage in this template to hide the Accordion row by default . That what I would acheive.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282275/accordion-in-appmaker/51283358#51283358) answer your question?

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately not. I've used the code in this topic but without success. Just to be surein the code there is 'YourElementName' . This part should be replaced by AccordionRowDetail right ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create style "collapsed" and "Hidden" in the style editor in the global style part to call them in the script above :

```
.app-AccordionRow.collapsed {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.app-AccordionDetail.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```